# How to pass a sequence of promises/futures?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, multiple-return-values

Is there any experimental or 3rd party library feature, which allows to pass a sequence (or wrapped set) of futures/promises? Consider an example:

```
struct header {};
struct body {};
struct footer {};

using footer_future = std::future<footer>;
using body_future = std::future<std::tuple<body, footer_future>>;
using page_future = std::future<std::tuple<header, body_future>>;

page_future generate_page() {
    // asynchronously generate a page
    // and return each piece via a promise right after it is generated
}

int main() {
    // unwrapping the sequence of futures.
    // next future is available only when successfully got the previous one
    auto page_fut = generate_page();
    auto [h, body_fut] = page_fut.get();
    auto [b, footer_fut] = body_fut.get();
    auto f = footer_fut.get();
}
```

I would imagine it could be something like `future_sequence<header, body, footer>`, where `get()` returns the next portion.

Or there is some fundamental flaw with this concept?

Comment: Is there a genuine serial dependency? if no then a flat list of futures may better.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried the code, I do not see any fundamental flaw with this.
With some template metaprogramming and variadic you should be able to do that.